# Read request URL from jenkins pipeline script

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

Is there a way to pass parameters to a pipeline script without setting up a parametrised build. I'm thinking if I can somehow gain access to the request URL that triggered the build I could read the parameters straight from there.

```
String url = currentBuild.getUrl() //Does a method like this exist?
Bool shouldDeploy = readValueFromQueryString("shouldDeploy") //exmaple
//continue to use variable in pipeline script.
```

I want to avoid having to set up parametrised builds through the UI because I don't always have access to the Jenkins box to change things and I think it will be kind of neat to be able to make these changes through a commit of my jenkins script.

Comment: I doubt supplying build parameters bypassing parametrised builds infrastructure is worth the effort. Parameters 1) have 'default value', when omitted; 2) passed exactly the way you want, as query string argument, with remote trigger.

Comment: I respectfully disagree. Our whole build process is now controlled through code. Every change is tracked in sc, the build can easily be reproduced on any machine (with _minimal_ jenkins configuration) and any change, from credentials to adding a new parameter can be done remotely and without needing access to our build machine.

Comment: Craigt, I believe that is what _yours_ Jenkins workflow requires, what your project needs/designed for; 
It may varies a lot though. 
Say, I'm currently in control of few build servers which are tuned to have highly customized jobs just because that is what business needs.
Jenkins is very versatile, that's what we do love it for